# spark-submit fails when submitting several jobs in parallel

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, spark-submit

I have a Spark application that I need to apply to different files and get the result as fast as possible, so in order to do this I have a created a python module which will prepare the files and then launch the different spark-submits jobs.

Before continuing I will explain a bit how spark-submit launches a job.

The native spark-submit's launching library creates a temporary text file in the TEMP directory with the command to execute, for more details [click here](https://www.mail-archive.com/issues@spark.apache.org/msg180965.html). The path to this file has the following syntax: .../AppData/Local/Temp/spark-class-launcher-output-**{RANDOM_VALUE}**.txt where RANDOM_VALUE seems to be a random number.

The thing is that when I launch multiple spark-jobs at the same time, i have a collision of RANDOM_VALUEs and so the parallelization gets in conflict because different spark jobs are using the same spark-class-launcher-output-**{RANDOM_VALUE}**.txt file.

So a simple solution for this will be to change the TEMP directory for every execution of spark, something like this .../AppData/Local/Temp/my_temp_**N** where N will go from zero to the number of parallel jobs minus one.

And here is my question. how can we change the TEMP directory for a spark-submit instance?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this problem by modifying the tmp directories but id didn't work. The problem is that it seems that spark writes this spark-class-launcher-file before even using the tmp directories for it's data processing. So at last I added a short delay between executions...